# Solve, in complex numbers, the equation $(z − i)^{3} =\overline{z} + i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve, in complex numbers, the equation $(z − i)^{3} = \overline{z} + i$

I tried raising left side to the power but after doing that I still wasn't able to solve that. Any tips? I heard something about Euler's formula but as far as I remember we have never used it during tutorials

Comment: should it be the same equation like above?

Comment: Your title and body don't match. I guess it's the one with the bar, right?

Comment: If I don't have a better idea for a complex equation, I put in $z=a+bi$ and see where it leads.  Have you tried that?

Comment: It should be conjugation. I just didn't know how to notate it and I had to search in google and then I forgot to change the title.

Comment: I would also note that $\overline z+i=\overline{z-i}$ which gives $|z-i|=1$ and it looks like $z-i$ is a root of $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is $$x^3-3xy^2+6xy-4x+i(3x^2y-3x^2-y^3+3y^2-2y)=0$$
and you must solve the System
$$x^3-3xy^2+6xy-4x=0$$
and
$$3x^2y-3x^2-y^3+3y^2-2y=0$$
the first equation can be written as
$$x(x^2-3y^2+6y-4)=0$$
and the second as
$$3x^2(y-1)-y^3+3y^2-2y=0$$
does this help?
from the first equation we get
$$x=0$$ or
$$x^2-3y^2+6y-4=0$$
we can eliminate $$x^2$$ from the second equation
$$x^2=\frac{y^3-3y^2+2y}{3(y-1)}$$ if $$y\neq 1$$
doing so we have on equation for $y$
$$-8y^3+24y^2-29y+14=0$$

Comment: I got something like this. But is it all that we can do?

Comment: I just have to analyze it and try to do that myself. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have turned it into
$x((x-2)(x+2)-3y(y-2))=0$ from the 1st
and $(y-1)(3x^{2}-y^{2}+2y)$ from the 2nd but still It hasn't helped a lot

Answer (score 4):

Set $u=z-i$, and note the equation can be re-written as
$$u^3=\bar {\rule{0pt}{1.35ex} u}$$
One obvious solution is $u=0$, i.e. $\color{red} {z=i}$.

Now suppose $u\ne 0$, and use the exponential form of $u$. The equation becomes
$$r^3\mathrm e^{3i\theta}=r\mathrm e^{-i\theta}\iff r^2\mathrm e^{4i\theta}=1\iff\begin{cases}r=1,\\4\theta\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}r=1,\\\theta\equiv 0\mod \dfrac\pi2.\end{cases}$$
So $u\in\bigl\{1,-1,i,-i\bigr\}$, and 
$$z\in\bigl\{\color{red}{1+i},\color{red}{-1+i},\color{red}{2i},\color{red}{0}\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: taking the conjugates on both sides gives $(\bar z + i)^{3} = z - i$, then substituting $\bar z = (z − i)^{3} - i $ from the original equation:

$$\require{cancel}
((z − i)^{3} - \bcancel{i} + \bcancel{i})^{3} = z - i \quad\iff\quad (z-i)\big((z-i)^8-1\big) = 0
$$

Comment: "taking the conjugates on both sides" what do you mean by that? I don't really understand : (

Comment: @JamesSmith In complex numbers $a=0 \iff \bar a = 0$, and so $\,a=b \iff \bar a = \bar b\,$. The latter is what I called "*taking the conjugates on both sides*". In this case taking the conjugates on both sides of $\,(z − i)^{3} =\overline{z} + i\,$ gives $\,\overline{(z − i)^{3}} = \overline{\overline{z} + i}$ $\iff {\overline{(z-i)}}^3 = \overline{\overline{z}}+ \overline {i}$ $\iff \left(\overline{z}-\overline{i}\right)^3=z-i$ $\iff (\overline{z}+i)^3=z-i\,$.

Comment: Right I got things that you wrote in your comment. But still at this moment I don't see the way how you got $((z − i)^{3} - \bcancel{i} + \bcancel{i})^{3} = z - i \quad\iff\quad (z-i)\big((z-i)^8-1\big) = 0$ from last equation in your comment.

Comment: @JamesSmith As I wrote, take $\,\color{red}{\bar z} = (z-i)^3-i\,$ from the original equation and substitute it into the parentheses on the LHS of $\,(\color{red}{\bar z} +i)^3=z-i\,$. Then you get $\,(z-i)^9=z-i\,$ and the rest follows.

Comment: Emm.. Wait a second. We got $(\overline{z}+i)^{3} = z-i$. Can't we put it into $(z-i)^{3}=\overline{z}+i$ so we get $(\overline{z}+i)^{5}=1$?

Comment: @JamesSmith I don't see where that $\,5^{th}\,$ power would come from.

Comment: $(\overline{z}+i)^{3} = z-i$ so putting it into the starting equation we get $((\overline{z}+i)^{3})^{3} = \overline{z}+i$ then $(\overline{z}+i)((\overline{z}+i)^{5}-i) = 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: @JamesSmith That's similar to what my answer does, except $\,\left(a^3\right)^3=a^9\,$, *not* $\,a^6\,$.

Comment: Right my bad. Thanks a lot.